# Convert string array to object with true/false flags

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Currently a `filter` parameter of a GET request is used to designate items' categories that will be requested from database and displayed.

The parameter contains comma delimited string - each string id for each category: `filter=complete,inwork,cancelled,ycancelled`.

I want to get a Ruby object with corresponding attributes that will be `true` or `false` dependent on string id presence in `filter` parameter. Current implementation is as follows:

```
filter = params[:filter].split(',') rescue []
fopt = OpenStruct.new(Hash[%w(complete inwork cancelled ycancelled).map {|fo| [fo.to_sym, filter.include?(fo)]}])
```

Could this be rewritten in shorter way?

Answer (score 3):

Code looks great to me. Here is a Rubocop-clean version with one change:

```
def fopt
  filter = (params[:filter] || '').split(',')
  OpenStruct.new(Hash[
    %w(complete inwork cancelled ycancelled).map do |fo|
      [fo.to_sym, filter.include?(fo)]
    end
  ])
end
```

Note the Rubocop [rule](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-rescue-modifiers) to avoid rescue in its modifier form.

Comment: Changing `rescue` to `||` makes the function crash if `params[:filter]` is `nil`. However, `(params[:filter] || '').split(',')` could work.

Comment: `string.split(',')` returns an array, which is never falsy in Ruby, so `|| []` will be never reached. As 200_success says, you have to do the `or` before the split.

Answer (score 3):

Some notes:

- Don't use a catch-all `rescue`, bad practice.
- Don't write lines so long, they are hard to read.
- Move all logic to models.

I'd write (in some model, not in a controller):

```
allowed_keys = %w(complete inwork cancelled ycancelled)
params_keys = params.fetch(:filter, "").split(',').map(&:strip).to_set
filter_attributes = allowed_keys.map { |k| [k.to_sym, params_keys.include?(k)] }.to_h
fopt = OpenStruct(filter_attributes)
```

Comment: Curious, why `to_set`? To remove duplicates? If so, why not use `array.uniq`? And doesn't `to_set` require you to require set?-e.g. `require 'set'`

Comment: 1) I use `to_set` not to remove duplicates but because `Set#include?` is O(1) while `Array#include?` is O(n). Not really needed with those data sizes, but feels conceptually more fitting. 2) In a bare Ruby script, yes, but Rails already includes `set`. Doesn't hurt to write it, though.